# FileWatcher in Quarkus using Camel

Tags: java, file, apache-camel, quarkus, watch

I need to make a file watcher that will watch a file and as soon as it is changed call a method.
I was trying to use  'org.apache.camel.quarkus:camel-quarkus-file-watch:3.0.0-M2' plugin, but I was not able to make it work.

Below is a code of my watcher:

```
@ApplicationScoped
public class FileWatchRoute extends RouteBuilder {

@NotBlank
@ConfigProperty(name = "CONFIG_FILE_FOLDER_PATH")
String configFilePath;

@Inject
OidcConfigProvider oidcConfigProvider;

@Override
@Startup
public void configure() {
    oidcConfigProvider.read();
    from("file-watch://" + configFilePath)
            .bean(oidcConfigProvider, "read");
}
```

}

Below is a code of OidcConfigProvider read method of which I need to call on file change:

```
@Dependent
public class OidcConfigProvider {
@NotBlank
@ConfigProperty(name = "CONFIG_FILE_PATH")
String configFilePath;

@Inject
ObjectMapper objectMapper;

@Inject
ConstraintsValidator constraintsValidator;

@Produces
@Singleton
@Startup
public OidcConfigDTO read() {
  //method logic
}
```

}

Please advise what I am doing wrong and how to fix it.
Thanks

Comment: Which OS do you run on? I tried a similar application on Linux and it was working fine for me.